Chrome DevTools Elements Panel Word Wrap Not Working
In Chrome browser DevTools, in the Elements panel, long lines of HTML code still require scrolling the Elements panel's contents horizontally, even when the "Word Wrap" option is selected in Settings > Elements > Word Wrap. The contents still overflow the width of the panel, even when a line of HTML has a whitespace. Can anyone replicate this problem?
I expect the Word Wrap setting to mean that all lines wrap to fit within the width of the panel, or, at worst, break at a whitespace.
If my memory is correct, this used to be the case: it used to be that no horizontal scrolling was ever needed. (I might be wrong about that. Can anyone confirm this?)
To make this even more inconvenient, when I scroll horizontally to the right with my keyboard arrow key, and then scroll back to the left with the left arrow key, it does not always scroll the panel contents but rather sometimes shifts focus completely.
I have no extensions installed, and have tried this using a Guest account as well, to be sure that it is nothing in my particular set-up. I'm using Chrome on a MAC with OS X Ventura.

Same here, both on my Chromium 124.0.6367.61 and my Chrome 130.0.6723.59
